# In cs_office map, how can I close the Garage Door?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Please see red arrow below that I added to [the original map](https://mr-aleks.github.io/maps.html).

How exactly is that garage door opened? Automatically once someone nears it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The door automatically opens and cannot be closed afterwards.

In the CS:Source version you would need to use the use key to open the door. It also could not to be closed after being opened.

In the 1.6 version of the map there was a toggle switch to open and close the door.
[image]